# How to add a menu in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add a menu, like the Instagram's one, where the user can go to the main page of Windows Phone application, or go to the settings page. How can I do in C# for Windows Phone 8.1 ? Is the menu always there in all page, or must be coded ? Are there any Windows icon available in the SDK ?

**UPDATE**

[image]

I'm looking for something similar to the red one. What is the difference between the red and the cyan one ?

Comment: Please add more description to your question, maybe code or research you have done. A screenshot with this menu can be also a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your hint and sorry for the bad explanation. I've just said something about Instagram, as example :)

Comment: The menu at the bottom (red one) is an application bar, you will find easly lots of information in the internet ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781230.aspx)). The top menu is probably their own control or modified default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean bottom appbar? If so, you should read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx and focus on Page.BottomAppBar, TopAppBar is in "big windows" only.